# Openlayers add features to vectorLayer from getFeatureInfo query

Tags: typescript, openlayers, geojson

Stack:

OpenLayers 8.2.0, Typescript 5.3.3, GeoServer 2.22

Goal:

Clicking on a map triggers a GetFeatureInfo request which returns feature info (correctly displayed) and geometries. I would like to display a vectorLayer containing the geometry of the last features returned by the GetFeatureInfo query. It should display any kind of Geometry Type.

Code:

```
// Setting the styles for any kind of Geometry Type
let white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
let blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
let width = 3;

let styles = {
  "Polygon": [
    new Style({
      fill: new Fill({ color: white })
    })
  ],
  "LineString": [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: white, width: width + 2 })
    }),
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: blue, width: width })
    })
  ],
  "Point": [
    new Style({
      image: new Circle({
        radius: width * 2,
        fill: new Fill({ color: blue }),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: white, width: width / 2 })
      })
    })
  ],
  'GeometryCollection': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'magenta', width: 2 }),
    fill: new Fill({ color: 'magenta' }),
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: undefined,
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'magenta' }),
    }),
  }),
  'Circle': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 2 }),
    fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' }),
  }),
};
styles['MultiPolygon'] = styles['Polygon'];
styles['MultiLineString'] = styles['LineString'];
styles['MultiPoint'] = styles['Point'];

// Creating the vectorLayer
const selectedGeom: VectorLayer<VectorSource> = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({wrapX: false}),
  style: (feature) => {
    let geomType: Type | undefined = feature.getGeometry()?.getType();
    return geomType ? styles[geomType] : styles["Point"]
  },
  properties: {name: "selectedGeom"},
})

// Getting the feature info with the attributes and the geometries
async function _getFeatureInfo(e: MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>) {
  selectedGeom.getSource()?.clear();

  const res = await geodataService.getFeatureInfo(
    // Request params to the geoserver
  );

  const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(res),
  });
  selectedGeom.setSource(vectorSource)

// Other stuff about attributes display but doesn't care here
```

Errors:

I can't figure out how to make it work but I tried a lot of syntax and I met a lot of error messages. The most explicit message is the one below:
`Argument of type 'VectorSource<FeatureLike>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>'. Type 'FeatureLike' is not assignable to type 'Feature<Geometry>'.ts(2345)`

Happening at the last line: `selectedGeom.setSource(vectorSource)`

Comment: `readFeatures` reads from a complete GeoJSON, not the features array of the GeoJSON (as in https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-image-forked-dlfddc?file=/main.js)
In your case you would need `features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(res),` insstead of `features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(res.features),`

Comment: Thx @Mike for your answer. I change my code using readFeatures(res) but I still get the same TS error: Argument of type 'VectorSource<FeatureLike>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>'.
  Type 'FeatureLike' is not assignable to type 'Feature<Geometry>'.ts(2345)

(I edited my code snippet)

Comment: I also tried with this single line of code:
`selectedGeom.getSource()?.addFeatures(new GeoJSON().readFeatures(res))` but I get the same error...

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15334

Comment: oh well done ! It is exactly my issue ! So I'll implement a typing workaround waiting for a bugfix release !
You can post this anwser so I will accept this ! :)

Comment: It would be better to use a WFS request

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @IanTurton.
Knowing that I perform a GetFeatureInfo request on a WMS, do you suggest performing a GetMap request in parallel in order to display the selected layers? Or are you suggesting to only use a WFS allowing specific features to be selected? Knowing that I'm loading a lot of data, I'm afraid of losing performance...
(in numbers: around ten WMS flows made up of several hundred thousand entities.)

Comment: If you want a single feature then a WFS request for that feature would be better than trying to parse the (non-standard) output of a getFeature request

Comment: I want to get all the features hit by the GetFeatureInfo. It could be only one feature but it could also be 10 or more. Maybe you've got a better knowledge of geoserver than me but I would like to understand why throwing two request (one GetFeatureInfo on a WMS and one GetMap on multiple WFS) could enhance this process ?